# How to update eyes of a face based on mouse click qt widget application C++?

Tags: qt, qt5, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsitem

I have a simple GUI created using qt creator as shown below

[image]

mainwindow.cpp looks like this

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QGraphicsEllipseItem>
#include <QGraphicsScene>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QGraphicsScene * scene= new QGraphicsScene(0,0,200,200);//creating scene to add graphics items
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);//adding scene to graphics view
    QGraphicsEllipseItem * face= new QGraphicsEllipseItem(0,0,200,200);//creating face
    scene->addItem(face);//adding face to scene
    QGraphicsEllipseItem * lefteye= new QGraphicsEllipseItem(50,60,30,30);//creating left eye
    scene->addItem(lefteye);//adding left eye to scene
    QGraphicsEllipseItem * righteye= new QGraphicsEllipseItem(125,60,30,30);//creating right eye
    scene->addItem(righteye);//adding right eye to scene
    QGraphicsEllipseItem * lefteyeball= new QGraphicsEllipseItem(58,67,15,15);//creating left eyeball
    lefteyeball->setBrush(Qt::black);//setting color of left eyeball
    scene->addItem(lefteyeball);//adding left eyeball to scene
    QGraphicsEllipseItem * righteyeball= new QGraphicsEllipseItem(133,67,15,15);//creating right eyeball
    righteyeball->setBrush(Qt::black);//setting color of right eyeball
    scene->addItem(righteyeball);//adding right eyeball to scene
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

I want to be able update the direction of eyes depending on where the mouse is clicked, can someone help with how to achieve this.

Comment: You should calculate the coordinates of the center of the black circle (eye). It should lay on the line between your mouse click and the center of the eye.

Comment: Ah, yet another [Xeyes](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xeyes) clone is born... :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to calculate angle between center of the eye and cursor position with `atan2` and shift pupil from the center by `X` for `A*cos(angle)` and by `Y` for `A*sin(angle)` where `A` is displacement from the center (constant value).

```
// eyeX, eyeY - coordinates of center of the eye
// pupilX, pupilY - coordinates of center of the pupil
double dy = eyeY - cursorY;
double dx = eyeX - cursorX;
double angle = atan2(dy, dx);
double shift = 10.0;
double pupilX = eyeX + shift * cos(angle);
double pupilY = eyeY + shift * sin(angle);
```